# Pandas Join Two Series

Tags: python, pandas

I have two Series that I need to join in one DataFrame.

Each series has a date index and corresponding price.

When I use concat I get a DataFrame that has one index (good) but two columns that have the same values (bad).

```
zee_nbp = pd.concat([zee_da_df,nbp_da_df],axis=1)
```

The values are correct for zee_da_df but are duplicated for nbp_df_df. Any ideas? I have checked and each series has different values before they are concatenated

Thanks in advance

Comment: Can you give a toy example which duplicates this (I can't reproduce it), also which pandas version are you using?

Comment: Problem solved. I updated my Pandas and everything works fine. In a separate issues there was dodgy data in my databases so head prices were the same and tail (most recent) prices were different. The DBA is now avoiding me ;-)

Comment: I also noticed [a problem with indices](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28460461/in-pandas-creating-a-panel-of-multiindexed-dataframes/28985439) in Pandas 0.13. Was that what you were using?

Comment: @RossMiddleton: please post your answer to your own question. Also please post a Minimal Reproducible Example, random data is fine.